# Android Java Check if Contact has name or not

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm trying to get contact in phone from ContentResolver query. I can get the contacts but I can't check if the contact has name or not.

My case is when the contact has no name, I will put an empty string, but `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME` return its number instead null.

Here my code to get the contacts

```
Cursor managedCursor = activity.getContentResolver()
                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                        "(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ? OR " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?)"
                        , new String[]{"%" + keyword + "%", "%" + keyword + "%"}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
        String firstChar = "";
        contacts.clear();
        while (managedCursor != null && managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            // Cleanup the phone number
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[()\\s-]+", "");
            if (name.length() > 0) {
                String first = name.charAt(0) + "";
                if (!first.equalsIgnoreCase(firstChar)) {
                    firstChar = first + "";
                    contacts.add(new Contact(Contact.TYPE_HEADER, firstChar));
                }
            } else {

                //when name length is 0 or name is null, I want to replace it with empty string
                name = "";
                contacts.add(new Contact(Contact.TYPE_HEADER, "#"));
            }
            Contact contact = new Contact(phoneNumber, name);
            if (!contacts.contains(contact)) {
                contacts.add(contact);
            }
        }
        setupAdapter(contacts, keyword);
        if(managedCursor != null){
            managedCursor.close();
        }
```

My previous way to replace it to empty string is compare it phoneNumber with name. If they are same, I replace it to empty string. But it can't detect when the nameless contact has multiple number.

is there anyone know how to detect if contact has name or no ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had worked with it. Let me share [it(git repo)](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/Secret-Phonebook/blob/189025e041901d2ce00153394a6597916eee217b/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/secretphonebook/home/HomeActivity.java#L47) with you

If you want to check user name is available or not. Than, you have write `if(name.isEmpty){}`

```
Cursor c;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    c=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC ");

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        //get contact list
        String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        //put value into Hashmap
        HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<>();
        user_data.put(Constant.NAME, name);
        user_data.put(Constant.PHONE_NUMBER, number);

        list.add(user_data);
    }



    //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
    CustomAdapterOfReadContacts customAdapter = new CustomAdapterOfReadContacts(HomeActivity.this,list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView

    c.close();
```

This way i get datas and send it to a adapter. Above source code is for save contact list. I am giving some source code for `call list`.

```
public void getCallLogs() {            
    int flag=1;
    StringBuilder callLogs = new StringBuilder();

    ArrayList<String> calllogsBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
    calllogsBuffer.clear();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    //cached name never deletes. If save it once to your contact. However you try to delete it. It won't delete from cached memory. I think if you `clear data` or `clear cache` than it will be deleted. I haven't try it.
    int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String cacheName = managedCursor.getString(name);
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        calllogsBuffer.add("\nPhone Number: " + phNumber + " \nCall Type: "
                + dir + " \nCall Date: " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec : " + callDuration + "\n");

    }
    managedCursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I have tried it and check every step by debugging with breakpoint. When the contact has no name, DISPLAY_NAME return phone number instead null / empty string. I test it with Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 (Custom ROM AOSP). So the isEmpty() condition is never fulfilled.

Comment: @Nauhalf Could you mark it as answer if I have successfully helped you? Cause, others can find the answer easily also. :) <3

Comment: it's not working :'( it's the screenshot when I debug, you can see the name is same as the number. https://imgur.com/TettjMM but in the contacts apps I set no name for its number 
Here the screenshot of detail contacts https://imgur.com/n4TexTt https://imgur.com/WSiYHou

Comment: @Nauhalf Look when you "call" someone. You get their name but, if you don't save number as nothing. Than it will be shown as "" nothing. So, you will get error. Or, user will upset or hesitate. That's why android save your number as name. So, you did it correct.

Comment: @Nauhalf You won't get something else. However you try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for both [Phone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone) & [StructuredName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName)

You can get both DataTypes by querying on the [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data) table directly.

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3};
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1); // display name (can be phone or email if name is missing)
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // phone / structured-name
    String data1 = cur.getString(3); // will contain phone number if this is a phone row
    String data2 = cur.getString(4); // will contain first name if this is a name row
    String data3 = cur.getString(5); // will contain family name if this is a name row

    String kind = "unknown";

    // get an existing "contact" from our HashMap, or create a new one
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        infos.add("display-name = " + name);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }

    switch (mime) {
        case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "phone"; 
            // add the phone to the contact
            infos.add(kind + " = " + data1);
            break;
        case StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "name";
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data2) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(data3)) {
                // found a real name! add it to the "contact"
                infos.add(kind + " = " + data2 + " " + data3);
            }
            break;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + kind + " - " + data1 + " - " + data2 + " - " + data3 + " - " + hasName);
}
```